# How can I get the element displayed with the setOnChildClickListener

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a little doubt about my particular program since it fails and I do not understand very well why, I have an ExpandableListView object that does the "Adapter" and a Fragment that calls this object. When displaying the elements of the list works, the problem is in the onChildClick what I intend is that when pressing an item in the list is saved in the TextView and show it to use later. As this is my program right now it only picks the first element from the list when pressed if I strike another element, the application stops working without giving me an error. What could I do to solve this? Thank you very much.

**This is the object of the ExpandibleList in which I call getChild**

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader ;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**And this is where I want to get the items from the list.**

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

//Expandable list Adapter
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    //Users
    private List <User> items = new ArrayList<>();

    //Obejeto a pasar
    User user = new User();
    String password;

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        //Botones
        TextPass = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.IdpasswordUser);
        TextName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        ExpandableListView ExList =(ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvExp) ;



                //Llamamos al boton fichar
        fichar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.fichar);

//Call ExpandibleList view child on pressed

        ExList.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

                 ShowItem(listDataHeader.get(childPosition));

                TextName.setText(listAdapter.getChild(groupPosition,childPosition).toString());

                return false;
            }
        });

        fichar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                password = TextPass.getText().toString();
                //SuperUsuario
                if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("cesi.tic")&&password.equalsIgnoreCase("123456789")){
                    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).EditarUsuario();
                    fichar.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                    TextPass.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                    TextDNI.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                }else{
                    LeerFirebase();
                }

            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    public void ShowItem(String id)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

How can I get the element displayed with the setOnChildClickListener

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've already solved the problem. I just need to remove 
// ​​ShowItem (listDataHeader.get (childPosition));

So the onChildClick would look like this:

```
 expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

                TextName.setText(listAdapter.getChild(groupPosition,childPosition).toString());

                return false;
            }
        });
```